# my cron job is not working whats wrong in it

Tags: php, laravel, cron, job-scheduling, cron-task

i apply a cron job where i want to update some values but my cron job is not working whats wrong in it here is my code in kernel.php

```
namespace App\Console;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')
        //          ->hourly();
        $schedule->command('cron:update-user-not-new')->daily();
    }

protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
```

and it is console/commands UpdateUserNotNew.php

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

     public function handle()
    {
         Customer::whereDate('visit_date', '>', now()->addDays(1)->toDateTimeString())
        ->update([
            'visit_clear' => 0
        ]);
    }
```

here visit_date is stored in this form in db " 2020-08-21 10:17:00 "

Comment: how did you setup the cron job to run the scheduler? and what about this "isn't working"

Comment: Does your command run successfully when you run it via console? Btw, are you sure that logic is valid? Update customers where the visit date is greater than tomorrow?

Comment: i did not test it on console im interny logic is right status should be update after 1 day

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a single entry to your server’s crontab file

- - - - - php /path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1

OR

- - - - - cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1